# Inserting the data through iBATIS into PostgreSQL database is not working

Tags: java, postgresql, ibatis

Inserting data into PostgreSQL database with [iBATIS](http://ibatis.apache.org/) is not working and not giving any exception. Please help me to get out of this.

This code is working some time but not every time. And code is properly executed, we are not getting any exception or any error.

The below code is used to insert the data into database:

```
public void insert() {
    map.put("customer", customer);
    map.put("created_by", created_by);
    map.put("created_date", created_date);
    map.put("modified_by", modified_by);
    map.put("last_modified", last_modified);
    map.put("total_cost", total_cost);
    map.put("tax", tax);
    map.put("bill_number", bill_number);
    map.put("date_of_sale", date_of_sale);
    try {
        SqlMapClient mapClient=GetDBConnection.sqlMapClientForLedger;
        mapClient.insert("insertTaxDiscountMemosbyanil", map);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I was using Tomcat web server.

Comment: I was using Tomcat web server.
In that server I have increased the heap size after that I I have tried for insertion that time data insertion was   syccessful.
but again in if i am doing same things more than 5 times that problem comes again.
What can be reason behind of this.

Answer (score 1):

Try add transactions.

```
try {
   mapClient.startTransaction()
   mapClient.insert("insertTaxDiscountMemosbyanil", map);
   mapClient.commitTransaction();
 } 
finally {
   mapClient.endTransaction();
}
```

Comment: I tried with same code but still it's not working and it's not showing any exception and still data has not inserted.